# Regular Expression to replace part of URL in XML file

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace, xml

I need a regular expression in Notepad++ to search/replace a string.   My document (xml) has serveral thousand lines that look similar to this:

`<Url Source="Output/username/project/Content/Volume1VolumeName/TopicFileName.htm" />`

I need to replace everything starting from Volume1 to .htm" /> to replaced with X's or some other character to mask the actual file names in this file.

So the resulting string would look like this after the search/replace was performed:

`<Url Source="Output/username/project/Content/Volume1XxxxxxXxxx/XxxxxXxxxXxxx.htm" />`

I am working with confidential information that I cannot release to people outside of my company, but I need to send an example log file to a third-party for troubleshooting purposes.

FYI the X's do not need to follow the upper/lower case after the replacement, I was just using different case X's for the hell of it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use word1.*.word2 to replace anything between two words, like so:[image]

![Notepad++ Regex][2]